# CakePHP 301 Redirects appending extra query string parameter

Tags: apache, cakephp, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I am trying to redirect old asp pages on a domain name so they link to their respective pages on the CakePHP version (using 1.3).  The domain name is the same.  These redirects are being added so results in search engines go to the new Cake page.

I have a bunch of Redirect 301's in my /.htaccess file (app/.htaccess and app/webroot/.htaccess are default).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]

   Redirect 301 /contacts.asp http://domain/contacts
   Redirect 301 /users.asp http://domain/users
</IfModule>
```

But for some reason, when I go to any of the urls to test the redirects, it appends an extra query string parameter.  For example:

Going to: `http://domain/contacts.asp` results in `http://domain/contacts?url=contacts.asp`

So the redirect is working but it is appending the `url` query string parameter.  I don't want to completely remove all query string parameters because some of the old asp links have query string parameters that I would also like passed to the corresponding Cake page.

I believe the "url" query string parameter is coming from the `app/webroot/.htaccess` file as seen:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Note that when I put all my 301 redirects into my Virtual hosts file, the `url` parameter is **not** appended.  I would like to keep all these redirects in my .htaccess file.  How can I prevent this `url` query string parameter from being appended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a case of mod_rewrite and mod_alias stepping over each other. The URI processing pipeline doesn't end when a `Redirect` directive is applied, it continues through the pipeline and mod_rewrite does its thing. Unfortunately, the end result isn't always what you want. You could just stick with mod_rewrite and drop the `Redirect` directives.

You can remove the 2 `Redirect` directives and add these 2 `RewriteRule`s *above* the ones that map requests to the `app/webroot`:

```
RewriteRule ^contacts\.asp$ http://domain/contacts [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^users\.asp$ http://domain/users [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I think I understand what you are saying.  Will `RewriteRule ^contacts\.asp$ http://domain/contacts [L,R=301]` keep parameters intact?  For example, would `http://domain/contacts.asp?contact=x` redirect to `http://domain/contacts?contact=x`?  Also, about the `Reddirect` directives method, is there any way I can move them around in those .htaccess files so they are the last ones evaluated?

Comment: @penguinegg Yes, existing query strings will automatically get appended. And no, moving around the `Redirect` statements won't affect anything because they are 2 different modules. One module runs and does its thing, then the other module runs and does its then, then at the end you have a URI and a redirect.

Comment: Does it get more complicated if I wanted to direct different sets of parameters to different locations in my app?  The following is just an example (so the url structure may not make sense).  Say I wanted direct `http://domain/contacts.asp?group=A&admin=1` to `http://domain/contacts/A/1` and `http://domain/contacts.asp?group=B&admin=0` to `http://domain/contacts/B/0`, but I still wanted `http://domain/contacts.asp` to redirect to `http://domain/contacts` (keeping any random parameters such as contacts.asp?view=all intact).  How would I have to modify the above?

Comment: @penguinegg you wouldn't modify the above, that's a completely separate thing. The above rules **only** apply to the URI `/contacts.asp` and `/users.asp`, nothing else. You'll have to come up with separate rules for that. It's not related to your CakePHP redirection problem.